# Better way of mixing up own framework with PHP zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Recently I've started to use Zend framework next to my own framework. The solution at this moment for instance for the module "partner" having a rewrite condition in htaccess like

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/partner/?(.*)
//redirect to build ZF
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/partner/index.php

// and the bootstrap files are

//index.php for Zend
set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '../../../library/php/');
include_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

//index.php for own framework
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'library/php/');

Is it possible to use Zend components just like it would with PEAR components?

Or the question with different perspective
Am I required to choose one of the two MVC patterns to go along with?

#### At the end I want to be able to use any library/framework for any module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ZF components similar to PEAR stuff. The only thing you will need to do is set the include path so, that ZF's requires will function:

```
set_include_path('path/to/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path())
```

where path/to/library contains the Zend directory.

At this point you can either initialize the ZF autoloader, or use require_once to load any classes you want to use.

Comment: I will try this

//load zend  
include_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

//load own framework components and use own MVC
function_exists("__autoload") || require_once('Loader.php');

$view = new View();
$controller = $view->createController();
$controller->render();